# Stop WPF failing silently?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, exception

Is it normal for WPF applications to fail silently, even in debug mode? Currently I am executing code in the richtextbox text changed event, and if it errors it simply stops calling the text changed event and so I have to step through all the code to find the point at which it stops...

As an example, I was casting a class to another class, but I was casting to the wrong class (typed it wrong..) and so the result was NULL. This resulted in some code directly after failing when I tried to use the class. Instead of an exception though, the program just continues to run as if a try-catch was round the whole thing (and inside the catch it be removing the text changed event)

Comment: It might have to do with the WPF ability to catch errors. Not sure though. You could try to add a [DataErrorInfoclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) and see if that catches it

Comment: Nope, that's not normal!  From what you've given, it's really hard to come up with any sort of answer except to say 'something's wrong'.  You're saying exceptions aren't being thrown?  What if you purposefully throw an exception?

Comment: @DanTheMan manually placing 'try-catch(exception ex)' around the suspected area, then placing a breakpoint in the catch to read the error works. But anyway Vincent Piel's solution fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have strange behaviours when your events handlers do not match the required signature.
Most simple for your issue is to have your Visual Studio stop on first chance exceptions. Go in Debug menu, exception sub menu, here you can choose which exception will stop the application.
Note also that first chance exception are displayed in the immediate window (Debug / Window / Immediate).

Comment: Thanks, I switched all the CLR exceptions from 'user-unhandled' to 'thrown' and it now works.